# How to check Amazon SNS write permissions in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-sns

How to check in app in Java has permissions to publish to Amazon SNS without publishing?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you are asking how to check whether the credentials that have been provided to an application could successfully use the `Publish()` command.

You could try [Testing IAM Policies with the IAM Policy Simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html). Apparently it can be called via API.